# PHP Amazon SQS Big Data

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-sdk

This is the first time for me using Amazon SQS.

I am still a little confuse how to store big chunks of data more than 50000 results from the database and push to it to the queue.

**AWS SQS instance**

```
require_once __DIR__.'lib/aws/aws-autoloader.php';

try {

  $aws_sqs_client = \Aws\Sqs\SqsClient::factory(array(
     'region'  => 'eu-west-1',
     'credentials' => array(
        'key'       => AWS_ACCESS,
         'secret'   => AWS_SECRET
     )
   ));

} catch ( Exception $e ) {

}
```

**MYSQL Query**

```
$q = 'SELECT user_id, user_email FROM user' // This has more than 50000 rows
// Is this correct way? it will create 50000 queues?
foreach ( $q as $key => $row ) {
  $result = $client->createQueue(array(
     'QueueName' => 'string',
    'Attributes' => array(
         'Queue_key_'.$key => 'string',
     ),
  ));
}
```

Or do I need to split the result into smaller result such as then count the number of pages

```
$q = 'SELECT user_id, user_email FROM user LIMIT 1000, 1' // Count total number of pages

$total_page = 500 // example;

for($i=1;$i<$total_page;$i++) { // then push it to the queue
  $result = $client->createQueue(array(
     'QueueName' => 'string',
    'Attributes' => array(
         'Queue_key_'.$i => 'LIMIT 1000, ',$i, // Mysql LIMIT
     ),
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating queues with the above, You have to push data to queue for the result. there is function named sendmessage SQS SDK which helps you to push data to SQS Queue.